# VueJS2 and Vuex deep nested state object mutation -- claims state variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have been trying to update `state.describeFields.user` and getting a *Error in render: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined"*

The section of code the error is dying on is:
`state.describeFields[payload.obj] = payload.data;`
where `payload.obj` is either 'user' or 'account'

It's a bit of daisy chain of calls, which I assume is causing the problem, but I am not strong enough of a developer to understand all of the implications. Getting there...  Thanks to you guys.

The Daisy chain begins with this.$store.dispatch('setCurrentIntegration', { data: {stuff:'here'}})

What should happen is this:

1. update state.integration (works)
2. get new items from indexeddb(`retrieveLocalDescribeFields`) for each of the `state.objects` values and save them to state.describeFields by property key (ironically actually saves them to state, but then errors)
3. if no data arrives from `retrieveLocalDescribeFields` then go out to remote api to gather data (code never gets here but does work before I moved all of this to vuex)

I've tried grouping the promises, resolving more specifically, I've tried console.log on state.describeFields and payload.data in the function that is erring, both output data to console that would be expected.

```
export default {
  state: {
    integration: {},
    objects: ["user", "account"],
    describeFields: { user: [], account: [] }
  },
  getters: {
    getCurrentIntegration(state) {
      return state.integration;
    },
    getCurrentDescribeFields: state => obj => {
      return state.describeFields.hasOwnProperty(obj)
        ? state.describeFields[obj]
        : [];
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setCurrentIntegration({ commit, dispatch, state }, payload) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        commit("updateCurrentIntegration", payload);
        let promises = [];
        state.objects.forEach(obj => {
          promises.push(dispatch("retrieveLocalDescribeFields", { obj: obj }));
        });
        resolve(Promise.all(promises));
      });
    },
    setCurrentDescribeFields({ commit }, payload) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        commit("updateCurrentDescribeFields", payload);
        resolve(true);
      });
    },
    setClearDescribeFields({ commit }) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        commit("updateClearDescribeFields");
        resolve(true);
      });
    },
    retrieveLocalDescribeFields({ commit, dispatch, state, getters }, payload) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          // go get data from indexeddb...
          // dexis call omitted

        if (theFields.length) {
          resolve(
            commit("updateCurrentDescribeFields", {
              obj: payload.obj,
              data: theFields
            })
          );
        } else {
          resolve(dispatch("retrieveRemoteDescribeFields", payload));
        }
      });
    },
    retrieveRemoteDescribeFields({ commit, state, getters }, payload) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          // go get data from remote api...
          // axios call omitted

        commit("updateCurrentDescribeFields", {
          obj: payload.obj,
          data: res.data.records
        });
        resolve(true);
      });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateClearDescribeFields(state) {
      state.describeFields = { user: [], account: [] };
    },
    updateCurrentIntegration(state, payload) {
      state.integration = payload.data;
    },
    updateCurrentDescribeFields(state, payload) {
      state.describeFields[payload.obj] = payload.data;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It all looks correct. Are you absolutely sure you don't have any typos in your `updateCurrentDescribeFields` mutation?

Comment: Works just fine in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/12acbf8e/3/).

Comment: I literally copied and pasted the code, no changes (other than removing axios and dexis promises...  this is the worst kind of problem... the kind that SHOULD work.... lol

Comment: Could be an old build you're running or something like that (browser cache, etc). Make sure everything is saved and you're running a clean, new build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  `-hangs head in shame-`

The problem was with a sibling component that changed as a result of the setCurrentDescribedFields (a pagination component).

It was that piece that was erring.  The trace just happened to trace back to the store mutations.   gah!

Thanks for the quick help.  Appreciate it!